# How to get the return value of an application in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am passing an argument to my test application via powershell. I wish to get the return value of the application once it finishes.

How can I get the return value of the application instead of the console output.

I'm running the application by running

```
Test.ps1 2
```

### Test.ps1

```
param ([string]$param1)
    
$path = "C:\Workspaces\myapplication\"
$executable = "Test.exe"
    
$filepath  = "$($path)$($executable) $($param1)"
    
Try 
{
    $Result = iex $filepath
        
    #this writes out the console output of Test.exe instead of the return value.
    Write-Host $Result  
    Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE  
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host "Exit Code"
    Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return value of the application"? Exit code?

Comment: my application returns an integer. depending on the scenario executed. for example a -1 for fail, or a 4, or 5 depending on the methods that were executed.

Comment: Returns how? In the exit code? If so, try replacing `Write-Host $Result` with `Write-Host $LASTEXITCODE`.

Comment: Use `& "${path}${executable}" "$input"` instead of `iex $filepath`

Comment: How about  `return $Result`? :P  The return isn't even needed just `$Result` without `Write-Host` should work, too...

Comment: Don't use `$input` as self-defined variable. This is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell. Choose another name for that var. Also, you have a typo: `Write-Hose` --> `Write-Host`

Comment: @Gebb, Thanks, $LASTEXITCODE works, There was a bug in my application. it was always returning 0.

Answer (score 2):

you should use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process):

```
$p = Start-Process $($path)$($executable) -ArgumentList $input
$p.HasExited
$p.ExitCode
```